# Can't get alignment formatted in Latex

Tags: formatting, alignment, latex, tex

I have written this code:

```
\begin{align*}
T_n &=&\frac{1}{(n+2)n!}&=&\frac{n+1}{(n+2)(n+1)n!} \\
&=&\frac{(n+2)-1}{(n+2)(n+1)n!}&=&\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}
\end{align*}
```

I want to get something aligned to the left after each `=` sign

But what I am ending up getting is :

[image: The distorted alignment here]

Answer (score 0):

The second `&` with the first equation sign is too much, have a lok at this:

```
\begin{align*}
    T_n &=\frac{1}{(n+2)n!}&=&\frac{n+1}{(n+2)(n+1)n!} \\
    &=\frac{(n+2)-1}{(n+2)(n+1)n!}&=&\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}
\end{align*}
```